# How to purge spark driver memory after collect()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have to do a lot of little `collect()` operations in my application to send data through HTTPcall.

```
val payload = sparkSession.sql(s"select * from table where ID = id").toJSON.collect().mkString("\n")
```

Is there a way to purge used objects to free some memory space in my driver between operations?

Comment: The **JVM** will free all unneeded objects from memory. However, you should review your design if you find yourself doing a lot of `collects` and wondering about memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I agree with @Luis Miguel Mejia Suarez here in that collects are generally bad practice and a bad code smell. I'd take a look at why you are doing collects, and determine if you can do this in a different way.

As for your actual question, the garbage collector will free any unreferenced memory once memory starts getting tight. The code snippet you showed above should be fine since the output of collect is immediately operated on and then discarded so that output should be removed during the next GC pause, while the mkString output would be kept. So make sure that this applies to the other collect statements you are using.

Additionally, if you are seeing long GC pauses, consider lowering your driver memory size, so that there's less memory to collect. You might also look into tuning your GC parameters. There's lots of documentation on that on the internet, and it is too intricate to describe in detail here.

Finally, you can force the JVM to run garbage collection. You should be able to use System.gc() (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc()). This is a Java function but Scala should be able to call it as well.